# how to see which checkbox is checked when add them dynamically

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a XML with a `TextView` and a `CheckBox` in it, now I add them to an Activity,
how many I add depends on how many questions there are, but if a checkbox is checked I want to see which one, how can I do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i< questions.size(); i++) {

    View view1 = View.inflate(Checklist.this, R.layout.question, null);
    TextView myText = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.questiontext);
    checkbox = (CheckBox) view1.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    layout.addView(view1);
    myText.setText(questions.get(i).question);

    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           //check which checbox is checked
        }
    });

}
```

This is how is add them to my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTag` to set tag on a checkbox:

While creating:

```
for (int i = 0; i< questions.size(); i++) {

    View view1 = View.inflate(Checklist.this, R.layout.question, null);
    TextView myText = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.questiontext);
    checkbox = (CheckBox) view1.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkbox.setTag(String.valueOf(i));
    layout.addView(view1);
    myText.setText(questions.get(i).question);

    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           //check which checbox is checked
           String tag= (String)buttonView.getTag();
        }
    });
}
```

This would give you tag (i), that will indicate the question number.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't work, they get all the same tag, if there are for example 3 questions the tag is on each checkbox: 2

Comment: Oh the `setTag()` works if I define the checkbox like this:
`final CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view1.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);`  

So Thanks !

Comment: Try  String tag= (String)buttonView.getTag(); What would be v in v.getTag()?

Comment: So remove the final again.